# How can we map catagorical codes in a dataframe back to the original data points in the original dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science

I have a simple dataframe that looks like this.

```
import pandas as pd
 
# Intitialise data of lists
data = [{'Year': 2020, 'Airport':2000, 'Casino':5000, 'Stadium':9000, 'Size':'Small'}, 
       {'Year': 2019, 'Airport':3000, 'Casino':4000, 'Stadium':12000, 'Size':'Medium'},
       {'Year': 2018, 'Airport':5000, 'Casino':9000, 'Stadium':10000, 'Size':'Medium'},
       {'Year': 2017, 'Airport':5000, 'Casino':10000, 'Stadium':15000, 'Size':'Large'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df = df.set_index(['Year'])
df

df_fin = pd.DataFrame({col: df[col].astype('category').cat.codes for col in df}, index=df.index)
print(df_fin.columns)
df_fin
```

[image]

Then, I convert everything to categorical codes, like this.

```
df_fin = pd.DataFrame({col: df[col].astype('category').cat.codes for col in df}, index=df.index)
print(df_fin.columns)
df_fin
```

[image]

Then, I am doing a basic basic classification experiment, like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier,AdaBoostClassifier,GradientBoostingClassifier

X = df_fin[['Airport', 'Casino', 'Stadium', ]]
y = df_fin['Size']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

clf = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=100)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Finally, if I want to make a prediction, I can do this.

```
print(clf.predict([[2, 3, 3]]))
```

The result is '0' for size, which is what I would expect for 2017. However, I don't want to use the categorical codes, I want to use the original records from the original 'df'.

How can I make a prediction like this?

```
print(clf.predict([[5000,10000,15000]]))
```

So I can get a prediction of 'Large'. Somehow I need to map the categorical codes back to the records in the original 'df'. How can I do this?

Comment: Why aren't you training with the actual values?

Comment: Since each category maps to multiple records, I'm not sure what you are expecting.  You can certainly do `years = df[df['Size'] == 0]['Year']` to get all the years that map to category 0.

Comment: Tim, because size is non-numeric. Also, it has something to do with the index, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be to only encode the target variable, as the features you posted are perfectly fine and can be used in a classifier without any preprocessing.

However if you want to go down the path of converting everything to categorical codes I would recommend using **OrdinalEncoder** for converting features and **LabelEncoder** for converting target, as that way it makes it easy to convert back and forth between original values and categorical codes.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OrdinalEncoder

feature_encoder = OrdinalEncoder()
target_encoder = LabelEncoder()

X = df.loc[:, ['Airport', 'Casino', 'Stadium']]
y = df.loc[:, "Size"]

X = feature_encoder.fit_transform(X)
y = target_encoder.fit_transform(y)

# training model
```

Having both encoders we can make predictions for original values

```
ex_x = [[5000,10000,15000]]
ex_x_encoded = feature_encoder.transform(ex_x)
ex_y_encoded = clf.predict(ex_x_encoded)
ex_y = target_encoder.inverse_transform(ex_y_encoded)
print(ex_y)
# ['Large']
```

Or even better, wrap it all in a function

```
def predict_og(X):
    # 1. Encode Features
    X_encoded = feature_encoder.transform(X)

    # 2. Predict 
    y_pred_encoded = clf.predict(X_encoded)

    # 3. Decode target
    y_pred = target_encoder.inverse_transform(y_pred_encoded)

    return y_pred
```

Comment: Very cool! I'll go with this!! Thanks!!